# Python mock.patch doesn't patch the correct import

Tags: python, mocking, flask, patch, twill

## Code

```
def test_get_network_info(self):
    with open(dirname(abspath(__file__)) + '/files/fake_network_info.txt', 'r') as mock_network_info:
        with patch('subprocess.check_output', Mock(return_value=mock_network_info.read())):
            self.assertEqual('192.168.1.100', get_network_info()[0])
            self.assertEqual('255.255.255.0', get_network_info()[1])
            self.assertEqual('192.168.1.0', get_network_info()[2])
```

## Error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_network_info (tests.test_tools.ToolsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/Documents/overseer/app/tests/test_tools.py", line 21, in test_get_network_info
    with patch('subprocess.check_output', Mock(return_value=mock_network_info.read())):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 1268, in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 1242, in get_original
    "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
AttributeError: <module 'subprocess' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twill/other_packages/subprocess.pyc'> does not have the attribute 'check_output'
```

## What I understand

My understanding of the problem is that `mock` is trying to mock [twill](https://github.com/ctb/twill)'s `subprocess` module instead of the python one.

## Questions

1. Am I doing something wrong ?
2. How can I specify that I want to patch the python `subprocess` module and not the twill's one ? (that may have been imported earlier in the test suite)**
3. Is there another way to patch the `subprocess` module ?

## What I tried

- I tried `with patch('tools.subprocess.check_output', ...`

Doesn't work.

- I tired to use a decorator ...

Doesn't work either

- I tired to patch directly the `subprocess` module `subprocess.check_output = Mock( ...`

Works but it's not good since it doesn't undo the patching.

## Some more informations

If I run just this test and no other tests, it works because twill's subprocess module never got imported. But as soon as I run a test using twill, the above test will fail.

[Here](https://github.com/ctb/twill/blob/master/twill/other_packages/subprocess.py) is the twill's version of subprocess wich looks like it has been copy pasted from an old version of python. It doesn't have any `check_output` function and that's why the test fails.

Twill's package comes from the [Flask-Testing](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/) plugin which I use extensively. I submitted an issue on github [here](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/issues/36).

I hope someone from the **lovely python community** can help. :)

Comment: Checked out twill's sources, and then the horror: sys.path.append(extensions) and other similar mess. Modules should never touch the path except when indeed changing the path is part of their feature. I think the author didn't figure out how to handle properly something and patched the path, and now you're stuck with a conflict ( you won't be able to properly use subprocess either, it's not a problem related to mock ). Try to move away from twill, as I see on github it was not updated since five years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment up there, due to bad practices in twill, the proper way would be to either fix twill, which may take some work, or move away to something else, but since you now heavily depend on Flask-Testing, it's not a cheap move either.

So this leaves us with a dirty trick: make sure to `import subprocess` anywhere before twill is imported. Internally, this will add a reference to the right `subprocess` module in `sys.modules`. Once a module is loaded, all subsequents `import` won't look anymore in `sys.path` but just use the reference already cached in `sys.modules`.

Unfortunately this is maybe not the end of the problem. Apparently twill uses a patched version of subprocess for some reason ; and those patches won't be available for him, since the plain built-in subprocess will be loaded instead. It's very likely it'll crash or behave in an unexpected way. If it's the case, well ... back to the suggestions above.